# Found 2 random bags in my son's set any idea what they are?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Help finding what these pieces are would be appreciated. Colors are brown, tan, gray and black there are wheels and eyes if any of this info helps

Comment: Was expecting something a bit more, um, *"unique"* in the bags after being lured here by "Hot Network Questions".

Answer (score 5):

Based on 6 parts that I identified:

- 4x4 plate (3031) in Tan
- 2 2x2 round plates (4032) in DBG
- 2x8 plate (3034) in White
- Slope 3x2 (3298) in Reddish Brown
- 1x6 brick (3009) in Tan
- 4 rims (8mm d. x 6mm w/ slot) (34337) in White

All these parts are in [Creative Ocean Fun (11018)](https://brickset.com/sets/11018-1/Creative-Ocean-Fun) set

[image: Creative Ocean Fun]

Comment: Comparring the round 2x2 with the "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Bar and Pin Holder (20482)" and the 2x2 in the bottom of the picture, I would guess those to be LBG.

Comment: Since this is one of those "Creative" sets I'd probably add a comment that elements included within the box are for creative building, rather specific model(s). Instructions include some inspiration models, which result in a number of elements being unused, thus may confuse as to why some extra elements being included.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity The round 2 x 2 is definitely DBG, You can see some LBG parts; plate 1 x 2 [w/ wheel bearing], brick 1 x 2 w/ hole, and plate 2 x 8. All clearly lighter than round 2 x 2 and not white

Comment: I only see one 2x8 plate, and @LKBricks determined that to be white. According to the inventories (I checked but brickset and bricklink) of the set he points to, it doesn't contain a 2x8 plate in white though, it does contain two in LBG, and it has a different color from the white elements, so I think I agree, it is LBG. That in turn makes the round 2x2 plates DBG, as I also agree there's a clear difference in color, and then the difference to the 2x2 at the bottom of the picture must be due to the lighting. I also struggled to find a set matching.